# Speeding up the response time in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel

Does anyone know how to create efficient indexes in MongoDB to speed up the response time? I'm getting the right response, it's just taking too much time. My  I need to get it below 100ms. I'm using the jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package.

https://pastebin.com/GHCwaJqT  Here is the response I'm getting. The limit is  15 rows and it takes 300ms

```
 $result = $this->model->skip($this->page)->limit($this->limit)->get();
```

Comment: Can you please show us the indexes on the database, the query you're running, and the # of records that you're retrieving back?

Comment: I have a standard index for the _id field, and the query is just a get , so it's getting 15 rows from the table @Ohgodwhy

Comment: If you want to improve indexing for a query you need to [`explain()` the query plan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/). If you aren't certain what query your application is generating, you can either capture slow queries from the MongoDB server log or enable the [database profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) to collect data into a `system.profile` collection.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your response (15 rows), it seems you are getting this data for the same user_id. If that is the case , what you can do is, create an index on user_id and use user_id as a filter in query to make MongoDB use this index.